# Fluent NHibernate mapping collection of the same type with propertyref and conditions

Tags: c#, fluent-nhibernate

So let's say I have a class:

```
public class Person
{
      public DateTime DateOfBirth { get; set; }
      public string Name { get; set; }
      public Person Parent 
      {
            get
            {
                return Session.QueryOver<Person>().Where(x => 
                               x.FamilyId == FamilyId && 
                               x.FamilyJoinOrder == null
                       ).SingleOrDefault();
            }
      }
      public IList<Person> Children { get; set; }
      public int? FamilyId { get; set; }
      public int? FamilyJoinOrder { get; set; }
 }
```

And I've mapped it like this:

```
public class PersonMap
{
    public PersonMap()
    {
        CompositeId()
            .KeyProperty(x => x.DateOfBirth)
            .KeyProperty(x => x.Name);

        Map(x => x.FamilyId).Nullable();
        Map(x => x.FamilyJoinOrder).Nullable();

        HasMany(x => x.Children)
             .Table("Person")
             .PropertyRef("FamilyId")
             .Where("FamilyJoinOrder > 0")
             .ReadOnly()
             .Fetch.Subselect();
    }
}
```

My problem is that the Children-collection doesn't work, it's always empty.

To clarify the conditions, here they are:

- FamilyId is the same with all family members (but no Family-table exists in DB)
- Children: FamilyJoinOrder > 0
- Parent: FamilyJoinOrder IS NULL
- the Children collection can be ReadOnly
- In real life the composite id has more fields and "cannot" be used as foreign key to the parent

How do I map the Children so that it actually works? 
Is it even possible?

Comment: Why has your entity access to the session? I would call this a very bad practise.

Comment: Oh, sorry, i forgot to mention this is just pseudo-code, the session variable actually comes from current principal's identity. And I guess the Parent could as well be mapped in the actual mapping class too..

Comment: It looks ok at the first sight. Did you took a look on the generated sql for the query? You can use [NhProfiler](https://hibernatingrhinos.com/products/NHProf) to achieve this. You should get enough information with it, to see whats wrong.